# realgud sets wrong path through tramp when setting breakpoint through GUI

Tags: tramp, gdb, realgud

I'm on my Windows machine with a file open on a remote linux server through tramp. I'm using `realgud:gdb` to debug my C++ file. In the (gdb) prompt, I can set breakpoint just fine using

```
(gdb) b /path/to/file.cpp:line_number
```

(note that the path doesn't include the `/plinkx:host:` prefix.

When I try setting a breakpoint using the GUI (red circle), the command that gets sent contains the plink prefix, which causes gdb to not process the command since its already residing on a remote:

```
<click on GUI breakpoint button>
(gdb) break /plinkx:host:/path/to/file.cpp:line_number
No source file named /plinkx.
Make breakpoint pending on future shared library load (y or [n])
```

Does anyone have experience with this, or know if its possible to parse the command being sent, strip any plinkx:host if in the path string, then resend the updated path?

Answer (score 0):

There is a communication issue here between gdb and realgud.

The question is how is it that realgud is supposed to know this is a remote file when it the GUI (red circle) is used?

When that is red circle is clicked, realgud asks the buffer name for the external file name and it is presumbly told `/pblinkx:host:/path/to/file.cpp`.

I suppose it might match notice that the beginning looks like a tramp remote file, but is there a sure-fire way to for it to *know* that. If so, then the problem could potentially be fixed reliably and that prefix could be stripped off.